# Running a SQL command in a method that does not contain a .getConnection declaration

Tags: java, sql

I am working on another project where i create a gui that has a button to connect to the database, and a button to run a sql command. Problem is that I am trying to use two different methods. one to connect and one to run a command.

Now i did get the code to compile fine, but spawns a runtime error when i go to run a command.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javasql.Javasql.exeCommand(Javasql.java:54)
    at javasql.UserInterface.actionPerformed(UserInterface.java:195)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here is my code:

```
 package javasql;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author KJ4CC
 */
import javasql.UserInterface;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Javasql {

    Connection connection;
    ResultSet result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserInterface gui = new UserInterface();
        gui.startGui();

    }

    public void connect(UserInterface gui) {
        gui.username.setText("client");
        gui.pass.setText("Brandy");
        try {
            String driver = (String) gui.driverSelect.getSelectedItem();
            String url = (String) gui.url.getSelectedItem();

            Class.forName(driver);
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, gui.username.getText(), gui.pass.getText());

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check you SQL Command, you may not have the privalges to execute such command!", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Javasql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("Database connected");

    }

    public void exeCommand(UserInterface gui) {
        Statement command;
        try {
            command = connection.createStatement();
            result = command.executeQuery(gui.command.getText());
            while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println(result.getString("ridername") + "      \t");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Javasql.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

ActionListener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
     Javasql sql = new Javasql();
    if (e.getSource() == connect){

     sql.connect(this);
    }else if(e.getSource() == clr){
        command.setText("");

    }else if(e.getSource() == exeSql){
        sql.exeCommand(this);
    }
}

}
```

I was thinking that my

```
Connection connect;
```

at the beginning of the code would work as if i had it in a different method. How could i stop this null pointer?

Comment: Your ActionListener creates a new instance of Javasql each time it is called. It creates one to make a connection and than another one (which has no connection) to exec some SQL.

Comment: Ok thanks! I knew i had an issue with instances, when i would get double the results.